# Nginx: How to proxy_pass a subdirectory to another subdirectory

Tags: nginx, proxypass

Please help, I am trying to proxy pass my *domain.com/travel* to a node app that has the content running here *255.255.255.255:1234/travel* ... How do I do this?

I currently have this:

```
location /travel/ {
    rewrite ^/travel(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://255.255.255.255:1234/travel;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

This partially works but it goes to the root of the application in *http://255.255.255.255:1234* instead. I was able to do this in Apache with this

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /travel/ http://255.255.255.255:1234/travel/
ProxyPassReverse /travel/ http://255.255.255.255:1234/travel/
ProxyPass /travel http://255.255.255.255:1234/travel/
ProxyPassReverse /travel http://255.255.255.255:1234/travel/
```

but since moving to Nginx I cannot replicate this. Help?

Comment: Please use `example.com` in your questions instead of a "this network" broadcast address.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use this:

```
location /travel(/.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ $1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://example.com:1234/travel$1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

I moved the regex capture to the `location` directive, although that doesn't make a big difference. Then, I added the `$1` to the end of `proxy_pass`, so that the `proxy_pass` destination URL gets the regex capture results appended to end of the URL.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a _500 Internal Server_ error

Comment: What does `error.log` tell?

Comment: Error log content `2017/04/04 13:16:53 [error] 5030#5030: *234917 the rewritten URI has a zero length, client: 255.255.255.255, server: host,com, request: "GET /travel/ HTTP/1.1", host: "host.com"`