# nginx reverse proxy in subfolder resulted in "bad gateway" or "file not found"

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to put a node.js app (node-red) using a reverse proxy.

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com

            location / {
                proxy_pass http://example.com:1880;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            }
}
```

This one **worked as expected**, I could access node-red from `example.com`

Then I need to use the root `example.com` for a homepage, and move node-red into **a subfloder**.

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com

    location / {
            root     /home/admin/nginx/www;
            index    index.html;

        }
    location /nodered/ {
                proxy_pass http://example.com:1880;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            }
}
```

For this attempt, **I could access the homepage** (index.html) when accessing `example.com`, but when accessing `example.com/node-red` I got `Bad Gateway error`

I also tried to change `location /nodered/` into `location /nodered(/.*)$` following [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/842436/502680), but then I got `404 error`.

Can anybody help? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I made a silly mistake.
The problem is in the trailing slash. The code below solved the problem

```
proxy_pass http://example.com:1880/;
```

Thank you to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/562850/502680).

Btw, I am not sure why the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) shows no trailing slash though.